# If a particular certificate file .crt or .cer etc has been installed and is active

Tags: powershell

I am having difficulty trying to get if a particular certificate from a certain path on a drive eg "c:\path\MyCert.crt" has been installed and if it is active.

I have the following:

```
$crt = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate;
$crt.Import("c:\path\MyCert.crt");
write-host "MyCert.crt expires after: " $crt.GetExpirationDateString();
$crt.GetName();
```

Which displays:

MyCert.crt expires after:  11/12/2021 2:12:31 AM
C=..., O="...", OU=..., OU="...", CN=...

Tried:

```
[bool](dir cert:\LocalMachine\ | ? { $_.subject -like "cn=MyCert" })
```

but not sure if this tells me if it is installed and active?

Can someone please help.

Comment: I think you should compare the [certificate thumbprint](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35694) rather than the subject name, that will check if it's *the same certificate*, not just another certificate for the same name. What do you mean by "active"? I'm not aware that a certificate can be installed, but inactive.

Comment: Ok thank you TessellatingHeckler. Will try to see how I can obtain the thumbprint from the file and compare against cert:\LocalHost\. As for active I just wanted to see if the cert is enabled and I thought that maybe there might have been a way to deactivate or disable a cert when it is installed so if you wished you could use different certs. I guess for testing purposes etc. Thank you now I know that when a cert is installed it is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @TessellatingHeckler suggested, you should compare thumbprints, as this will tell you if the *specific* certificate is installed. Otherwise you could end up getting but a true value even if the certificate has been renewed or something else has happened to change the cert.

The other problem you'll come across is that, by default, `Get-ChildItem` (alias DIR) won't search down a path recursively, so you'll only see the folders that a Certificate can live inside by running what you've got in your example:

```
[1] PS C:\> dir cert:\LocalMachine\


Name : TrustedPublisher

Name : ClientAuthIssuer

Name : Remote Desktop

Name : Root

Name : TrustedDevices

Name : CA

...
```

You'll also notice that importing a crt file as an 'X509Certificate' object won't show you the thumbprint. You have two options here, look at the file using the `Get-PfxCertificate` (I'm not sure when this was introduced so I'm not sure if you'll have it available), or you can import the crt file as an 'X509Certificate2' object.

Forgive me for expanding out the alias' in your snippet, but the following will do the trick:

```
$crt = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$crt.Import('c:\certs\CertFile.crt');

[bool](Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\ -Recurse | Where { $_.Thumbprint -eq $crt.Thumbprint })
```

Comment: Thank you Windos. Was Googling around to get ideas but your approach will work. Now to make it more generic and paramatized.